# Uncaught Error: Object of class Seller could not be converted to string

Tags: php, string

> Uncaught Error: Object of class Seller could not be converted to string

```
  public function register_seller(){
    global $database;

    $this-> name = trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name)));
    $this-> email = trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email)));
    $this-> password = trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->password)));
    $this-> image = trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->image)));
    $this-> address = trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->address)));
    $this-> description = trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->description)));
 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $this -> table (name, email, password, image, address, description) VALUES(
        '" .$database-> escape_value($this->name). "',
        '" .$database-> escape_value($this->email). "',
        '" .$database-> escape_value($this->password). "',
        '" .$database-> escape_value($this->image). "',
        '" .$database-> escape_value($this->address). "',
        '" .$database-> escape_value($this->description). "'
    )";
    $seller_saved = $database->query($sql);
    if($seller_saved) {
        return  true;
    } else{
       false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: For info : `else{ false; }` has no effect.

Comment: You should have a look to prepared statements and parameterized queries.